# perl conditional split/join

Tags: arrays, perl, join, split

Im trying to parse a very large list where some fields are blank thus the rows are not needed.  What I want to do is identify where the row is blank in that certain field and omit it.  Can anyone help?? I am new to perl and am not sure if i should use split, join, or either.

```
id  name    food    drink
1   joe chips   pop
2   jack    chicken beer
3   josh    pizza   beer
4   jim     beer
5   john    cookies milk
```

This is an example table that is `\t` delimited.  Notice that #4 Jim is missing a food item.  Because of that, I want to delete the entire row.  I'm not even sure where to begin on this one.  I was hoping an expert would have a solution for this scenario.

Comment: How do you know how many elements are in the string? Is the first element of the array containing the line format to follow (in your example, `id name food drink`), or do you get it by some other means?

Comment: @AntonH I want to treat each field in the list as an element in the array, thus there will be 4.  If one of the elements($element[]) are blank, i want to omit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very straightforward using autosplit and a command-line program. Like this

```
perl -aF\t -ne "print if $F[3] =~ /\S/" milk.txt
```

**output**

```
1       joe     chips   pop
2       jack    chicken beer
3       josh    pizza   beer
5       john    cookies milk
```

I've assumed the numbers at the start of the line are part of the data

Comment: works great!! also @mpapec that worked as well but the syntax used above is more familiar to me.  thanks guys!

Comment: actually @borodin i have another question related to this topic...what if i wanted to run a program on just this portion of the array??

Comment: @joshE: You mean you want to run a program with these filtered lines as input? You could pipe the output of this code to the input of your program, or you could just filter out the records you don't want inside the `while` loop of your program, assuming it's Perl?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, not doing a one liner...

The [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) takes a string and splits it, so each *item* is an element in the array I'm returning. The `join` goes the other way. It allows me to *join* the elements of an array into a single string.

Note that I use `/\s+/` for my split. This matches any continuous whitespace and will work with a single tab, or if a person entered two tabs to keep things looking nice, or if someone accidentally types a space or two before pressing the tab key.

You want to make sure all of your lines have four elements. Since we split the line into an array, we can test to make sure that the array for that line has four elements in it. If not, we can skip it.

To test the how many elements an array has, you simply use the array in a *scalar context*. My comparison `next if @array < 4;` is doing just that. The `next` will skip to the next iteration of my loop without going through the rest of the loop code. You'll commonly will see `next if...` or `next unless` type statements in Perl. It's a great way to skip over lines in a file or array that don't match your criteria.

The `__DATA__` is a neat trick in Perl. All lines after `__DATA__` are treated as a file. When I access `<DATA>`, it's like if I read from a file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

for my $line ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;       # Always "chomp" right after a read
    my @array = split /\s+/, $line;
    next if (@array < 4 );
    printf "%-2.2s  %-10.10s  %-10.10s  %-10.10s\n", @array;
}

__DATA__
id  name    food    drink
1   joe chips   pop
2   jack    chicken beer
3   josh    pizza   beer
4   jim     beer
5   john    cookies milk
```

This will print out:

```
id  name        food             drink
1   joe         chips            pop
2   jack        chicken          beer
3   josh        pizza            beer
5   john        cookies          milk
```

Answer (score 1):

It will skip lines which have at least one empty value,

```
perl -F'\t' -wane 'print if !grep !length, @F' file
# or
# perl -F'\t' -wane 'print unless grep !length, @F' file
```

output

```
1       joe     chips   pop
2       jack    chicken beer
3       josh    pizza   beer
5       john    cookies milk
```

or just to check third column,

```
perl -F'\t' -wane 'print if length($F[2])' file
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify a certain field instead of saying if any are blank omit??  Say I am just looking to see if the field 'Food' is blank.